# Use global files in e2e tests in NestJs with Jest

Tags: module, jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing

I'm trying to test my endpoints using Nest e2e tests with Jest and supertest.

I have the following folder structure for all files in the project:

```
- src/
- - global/
- - - database/ (with module)
- - - enums/ (without module)
- - - helpers/ (without module)
- - - schemas/ (without module)
- - (all other modules in folders)
- - app.module
- - main.ts
- test/
```

When I run the tests following error occurs:

> Could not locate module src/global/enums mapped as:
> {rootDir}/test/$1.

```
Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^src\/(.*)$/": "{rootDir}/test/$1"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}
```

The enums are imported in a DTO file inside one of the modules.

How can I tell Jest that the global folder does not only has modules and the enums are just exported objects?